# Vector that always points to and touches circumference of ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections, curves, parametric

Lets say I have an ellipse. Starting from the center of that ellipse is there a way I could find a vector (line segment) that when "rotated" around the initial point of the vector, the end point will always touch the circumference? if there is a way?

Edit: for clarity I'll explain my question better.
First, I have draw an ellipse. it can be of any configuration.
Next I draw a point from within anywhere in the ellipse's circumference. Now comes the part I need help with.
Is there a equation/algorithm anything that allows me, knowing the parameters of my ellipse, to draw a line from wherever I place my point from within the ellipse to the exact edge of said ellipse. The idea why I said "rotation" was because I envisioned the line being drawn as a function of time, so whatever "t" value of time with put in our function. we would get a corresponding coordinate value for the edge of the circumference.

(see figure for clarity). [image]

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center

Comment: Are you just rotating the vector, or are you also allowing the vector to change length? If you want the vector to just rotate without changing its length then that is not possible unless the ellipse is a circle. A proper ellipse a "squashed" circle, and no part of it is a circular arc any more.

Comment: Your picture does not add clarity: What is input data and what is desired output? Do you need to find length of blue vector as function of rotation angle or what?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yes, the vector changes length, rotating is not a good word to use here (why I put it in quotations) it's in more sense a function that can trace a line from any point within an ellipse to any point on the ellipse's edge

Comment: So pick a point inside the ellipse, pick a point on the ellipse, and trace the line segment between them. As Ivan says, it is unclear what you are asking for. How is your ellipse defined? Do you have an equation for it? What is it you want to calculate? What do you need it for? What is this function you speak of? What are its arguments and what is its output?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis well I'm asking if there is a function that allow me to do just that but for all points on the ellipse like a function of time where an input will yield a line drawn from that point to that specific input position on the circumference

Answer (score 4):

If the ellipse origin is in $(0, 0)$ and the ellipse passes by points $(a, 0), (0, b), (-a, 0), (0, -b)$, a parametric equation is, for $\theta$ in $[0, 2\pi[$:
$x = a \cos \theta$
$y = b \sin \theta$

Then, the vector $v$ between a point $(x_0, y_0)$ and this point $(x, y)$ has coordinates:
$v_x = a \cos \theta - x_0$
$v_y = b \sin \theta - y_0$

(As remarked by @Intelligentipauca, please note that $\theta$ is *not* the angle made by the vector with the $x$ axis, even when the vector origin point is $(0, 0)$. It *is* this angle for a circle, i.e. an ellipse with $a=b$. On an ellipse you can find back this angle by "stretching the ellipse to a circle", i.e. vertically projecting the ellipse point onto a circle with radius $a$ and same center).

Comment: You should make clear that $\theta$ is NOT the polar angle.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca You are right, I will do it. I did not say it first, because I would have liked to say what $\theta$ is, geometrically, and this is not so obvious (without drawing a figure).